# Parse.com push notification not working after changing the package name

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

Parse.com push not working after changing the package name.

I have checked the Manifest file, it contains the new package name only.

Not sure what is really the problem.

Comment: Can you include your Manifest?

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure to update all the references to your app's package in your manifext.xml

2) Make sure to update all the references to your app's package in your build.gradle

3) Do a File > Invalidate caches / Restart

Rebuild and it should work :)